# rabbitmq queue latency with easynetq

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, easynetq

i have written a simple publish\subscribe tool for rabbitmq using easynetq driver. However the possible seems to be horrible. i send messages with a Datetime field on it and measure the time it reaches to be received by the subscriber.

**Queue Latency = DateTime to reach subscriber - originating datetime in seconds**

Assuming the Queue is FIFO which it should be. I noticed that over time the latency of the queue increased substantially. I could not explain the results. Any similar experiences.

The messages were approximately 200Kb in size and the prefetch count was set to 5 in the subscriber. the publisher confirms was turned on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I noticed some performance issues with EasyNetQ and have [reported them in their Github project page](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/issues/517). However, I haven't heard back from them in a couple of months, so maybe they are not interested in investigating. Below is a graph of time consumption for publish/subscribe when publishing *n* messages where *n = 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500*. As the message rate increase, so does the latency.

[image]

These performance implications was one of the reasons why we migrated from EasyNetQ to [`RawRabbit`](https://github.com/pardahlman/RawRabbit), a vNext compatible framework with an API similar to EasyNetQ:s. It might be something worth checking out for your project? If you're experience similar performance problem with `RawRabbit`, you are [free to register an issue](https://github.com/pardahlman/RawRabbit/issues/new), and I'll have a look at it as I'm one of the main authors.

Hope this helps!